# Scrollable Div only scrolls structure but not data of Primefaces datable in IE8 and IE9 compatability mode

Tags: internet-explorer, jsf-2, primefaces, scrollbar

The div scrolls the table, but the data doesn't move. It works fine in IE9 (non-compatability mode) and Firefox. A simple example is below. Anyone know of a workaround for this?

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
                      "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">

<h:head>
    <title>Carousel Test</title>
</h:head>

<h:body>

    <h:form id="evaluationForm">

        <div style="overflow:auto; height:200px">
            <p:dataTable value="#{evaluationBean.items}" var="item">
                <p:column headerText="ID">
                    <h:outputText value="#{item.id}" />
                </p:column>
            </p:dataTable>
        </div>

    </h:form>

</h:body>

</html>
```

Thanks,
Neil

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just turn off IE compatibility modus by

```
<h:head>
    <f:facet name="first">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge" /> 
    </f:facet>
    ...
</h:head>
```

Note that the `<f:facet name="first">` is specific to PrimeFaces. So if you're not using it, just remove it and put the `<meta>` tag in the very top of the `<h:head>`, it'll work as good as well. The key point is that it has to appear *before* the PrimeFaces-generated `<link>` element pointing to the theme CSS. See also the [MSDN document](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj676915%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

> The X-UA-Compatible header isn't case sensitive; however, it must appear in the header of the webpage (the HEAD section) before all other elements except for the `title` element and other `meta` elements.

Which thus means that it won't work when appearing after for example a `<link>` element.

Comment: That's great thanks. I know that in some circumstances things don't work so well in IE8, so we have people on IE8 stay in compatability mode by default. As I'm using templates, is there a way of making it conditional. I tried wrapping <ui:fragment> round it (with conditional rendering) and it didn't work.

Comment: Wrap it around `<meta>`, not `<f:facet>`. The `<f:facet>` must in all cases be an immediate child of the desired parent.