# IE9 rendering IE8 document standard

Tags: jsf, xhtml, primefaces, glassfish, internet-explorer-9

I need my application to run in IE9 document standard and I cannot figure out why it automatically renders in IE8 document standard.

I'm using JSF 2.1.17 and Primefaces 3.4, running in Glassfish 3.1.2. My IDE is Netbeans-7.1.2. When I open the developer tools in IE, under the "HTML" tab it shows:

```
<--!DOCTYPE html-->
<html  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
```

However, under the "Script" tab it shows:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN">
<HTML lang=en xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en">
<HEAD>
<META content="IE=8.0000" http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible">
```

**I have looked through all my pages and templates and NO WHERE can I find the meta content="IE=8.0000" or the !DOCTYPE that is shown above**. It is very odd.

All my pages have:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

My main template has this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 

<html   xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en" 
        xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
        xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
        xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
        xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core">
```

Other pages have:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
                xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
                xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
                xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
                xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
                template="/layout/someFile.xhtml" >
```

Here are the things I have tried:

1) Updated the Glassfish JSF to 2.1.17, since I read that there was a bug with older versions of Mojarra that caused it to ignore the DOCTYPE.

2) I added:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9" >
```

to every page, hoping it would enforce IE9, but this did not work.

3) I then tried using content="IE=Edge", still no changes.

4) I changed my DOCTYPE to:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
 "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
```

unsure if XHTML needed this strict DOCTYPE to render properly. But this did not work.

Any help would be great. I have done a lot of research trying to sort this out, however I am new to web development, so I my understanding is quite limited.

Comment: What exactly is the source the browser actually retrieved? Rightclick, *View Source*. Is this the same in Firefox/Chrome/etc? As to the meta tag, see this duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13742786/scrollable-div-only-scrolls-structure-but-not-data-of-primefaces-datable-in-ie8/13743222#13743222

Comment: The source the browser retrieved is the correct one. It is the same in FF/Chrome/Safari. The only issue is the doc mode. Do I need to add 

   <f:facet name="first">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge" /> 
    </f:facet>

to every page or just the template pages?

Comment: Wrapping the meta tag in a facet solved the issue. Is there a good source on where to read more about when to wrap tags in a facet?

Comment: @patient957 I am glad you figured out the problem, that is strange.  Perhaps you can post your findings as a self answer to benefit future visitors searching for this problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> *I added:*
>
> ```
> <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9" >
> ```
>
> *to every page, hoping it would enforce IE9, but this did not work.*

According to the [MSDN document](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj676915%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) on this meta tag,

> The X-UA-Compatible header isn't case sensitive; however, it must appear in the header of the webpage (the HEAD section) before all other elements except for the title element and other meta elements.

this must appear **before** all other elements expect for `<title>` and other `<meta>` elements. If you investigate the JSF/PrimeFaces-generated HTML closely, you'll see that there's a PrimeFaces specific `<link>` element before that which would block the `X-UA-Compatible` header from doing its job.

PrimeFaces [supports](http://blog.primefaces.org/?p=1433) several facets for the `<h:head>` so that you can control the ordering of the head resources. The following should do it for you:

```
<f:facet name="first">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9" /> 
</f:facet>
```

Again, this is specific to PrimeFaces, not to standard JSF.

Comment: Thanks again, very helpful and fixed the issue.